# Which .NET, EF and ASP for a new project?

Tags: asp.net, .net, entity-framework

I've done a reasonable amount of reading around on .NET Standard v .NET Core, watched a course on PluralSight regarding EF Core and done further reading on EF 6 v EF Core, and done some reading up in ASP.NET Core v ASP.NET.

What I still can't decide is what the recommendation is if I'm about to embark on a new project with a web interface.  It's against SQL Server, and will be hosted on Windows and users will be connecting from Windows desktop machines.

As it's all Windows .NET Standard would suffice - though I could use .NET Core, I know that EF Core works against .NET Standard, I assume ASP.NET Core will as well.

At a later date there could be an extension for mobile functionality, but that could be written as an extension/module using Core or similar.

It's vary hard to find a clear answer on this as even on Microsoft's Docs site, the EF initial pages haven't been updated since the release of EF Core 2 and prior to that they seem to suggest that unless you need it, stick with EF 6.

Thanks

Tom

Comment: New innovation would only come to .NET Core, so you should now know the answer.

Comment: OK, I hadn't seen that anywhere on the .NET Docs site (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/).  It all suggest that .NET Standard and .NET Core will continue to be developed.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I was lead astray by some articles I read on .NET Standard.

However, I now have an answer from a post on the MSDN site [see here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6d7da975-f5eb-498f-8daf-7039a73dbe9e/which-net-ef-and-asp-for-a-new-project?forum=netfxbcl)